# I want to filter my product on the bases of rating, How can i do that?

Tags: django

**My Models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def no_of_ratings(self):
        ratings = Rating.objects.filter(product=self)
        return len(ratings)


    def avg_rating(self):
        ratings = Rating.objects.filter(product=self)
        sum=0
        for rating in ratings:
            sum += rating.rating
        if len(ratings)>0:
            return sum/len(ratings)
        else:
            return None


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Rating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'product'),)
        index_together = (('user', 'product'),)
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from .models import Product, Rating

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields =('id', 'title', 'description', 'no_of_ratings', 'avg_rating')


class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ('product', 'user', 'rating')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Rating, Product
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
from .serializers import ProductSerializer, RatingSerializer


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(product__rating__gte = 4 )
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

class RatingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Rating.objects.filter(rating__gte = 4)
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Hi, I'm new in Django Rest Framework, I want to filter my product on the bases of rating, but my filter doesn't work, I have two models classes Product and Rating every Product have a rating( Foreign key ), I want to list only +4 rated product, how can I achieve that, and can I filter results to get models with specific rating?

Answer (score 0):

With `queryset = Product.objects.filter(product__rating__gte = 4 )` you look up products and filter them by their field `product` but your product instances don't have this field or property.

In your views.ProducViewSet You should filter for something like

```py
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(rating_set__rating__gte = 4 )
    # ...
```

instead. `rating_set` is the default name to access foreign keys in the other direction (from the model where it's not defined in) You can use the `related_name` parameter in the ForeignKey to set this to a custom name like `product_rating`. (Notice the use of single `_`, it wouldn't work with double `__`)

Comment: Thank You so much, It's done now I used related_name